# Hovering link sometimes triggers strange mouse pointer behavior

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Sometimes, randomly, when hovering links on a page, the mouse pointer will
quickly shift between its normal pointer and the hand icon.

**Actual Results:**
The mouse pointer will quickly shift between the normal mouse pointer and the
hand icon.

**Expected Results:**
Keep displaying the hand icon.

**Browser :** Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)

**OS :** OS X Yosemite

**HTML :**

Edit : Oops ! It's a really `a` ! no `span` sorry.

```
<a href="#" class="link">View</a>
```

Is there a solution for that ?

Comment: Can you set up an example showing this behaviour?

Comment: You are opening an `a` tag but closing a `span` tag which may result in some funky side effects. Do you get the same issue if you use `<a href="#" class="link">View</a>`?

Comment: Ooops my bad ! It's a really a ! no span. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The html code is not complete.
If span have dimensions (width and height), it can be bigger than the a tag.
Use CSS, something like that:

HTML:

```
<span class="link_span"><a href="#" class="link">View</a></span>
```

CSS:

```
.link_span {
cursor: pointer;
}
```